# readjust QTableView after changes to the model

Tags: python, qtableview, pyside2

I use PySide2==5.13.0

I have a custom QTableView. A QAction invokes the remove method below. All works fine but the table view itself does not adjust its dimensions (same with the add method).

```
def remove(self, row):
    print(f'remove {row}')
    self.model.removeRow(row)

    # I tried a few of the methods
    self.table_view.resizeColumnsToContents()
    self.table_view.restoreGeometry()
    self.table_view.adjustSize()  # resize...
```

Screenhot shows that the model has been processed correctly (row is gone). But the table view itself needs to remove the row, too.

[image: empty row at the end needs to go]

I believe it is sth. small and I am studying the documentation for hours but could not find the solution to this problem (yet). Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in the documentation [beginInsertRows](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QAbstractItemModel.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.beginInsertRows). It totally makes sense now. I needed to add beginRemoveRows() and endRemoveRows() calls to the removeRow implementation in my model.

Here the relevant details from the documentation in case you are curious:

Models that provide interfaces to resizable data structures can provide implementations of insertRows() , removeRows() , insertColumns() ,and removeColumns() . When implementing these functions, **it is important to notify any connected views about changes to the model’s dimensions both before and after they occur**:

- An insertRows() implementation must call beginInsertRows() before inserting new rows into the data structure, and endInsertRows() immediately afterwards.
- A removeRows() implementation must call beginRemoveRows() before the rows are removed from the data structure, and endRemoveRows() immediately afterwards.

...

Comment: For a next occasion, you must provide a [MRE] since your answer is a solution for a particular case that might have been generated by a problem other than the model.